# Matlab code crashes and gives error: Dimension of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

Kindly have a look at this code and help me out. I am doing something wrong with the Matlab line command. The code give warnings and then crashes. The error is in the 2nd last line.

```
while ~isDone(videoSource)
frame = readFrame(videoSource);
mask = detectObjects(frame,Fgdetector);
[areas, centroids, bboxes]= step(blobAnalyser,mask);

% tracing boundires around the detected obbjects

% BW = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
[B,L] = bwboundaries(mask,'noholes');
imshow(label2rgb(L, @jet, [.5 .5 .5]))
hold on

 for k = 1:length(B)
 boundary = B{k};
 plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'w', 'LineWidth', 2)
 %for star skeleton
 x = boundary(:,2);
 y = boundary(:,1);
 indexes = convhull(x, y);

 hold on;

%  plot(x(indexes), y(indexes), 'm-', 'LineWidth', 2);
 line([x(indexes(k)), centroids], [y(indexes(k)),centroids ], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);

end
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error? In that line check the size of each variable you are concatenating.

Comment: This line :line([x(indexes(k)), centroids], [y(indexes(k)),centroids ], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);

Comment: It isn't crashing.  It's exiting quite normally due to a user error.

Comment: Can you tell me how to solve this error??

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect is happening is that `centroids` is a N x 2 array, or a 2 x N array and you are trying to concatenate a matrix with a single value to create another matrix.  The sizes are inconsistent and so that's why you're getting that error.  I don't know what shape `centroids` is (i.e. if it's `N x 2` or `2 x N`) because `detectObjects` is something you wrote, or a function that exists in a later version of MATLAB that I don't have access to, so one of these should work.  When you use `line` you need to provide the `x` locations and ending `y` locations for each segment of the line that you want.

Assuming that the first row/column is the `x` coordinates and the second row/column is the `y` coordinates, do this:

## `centroids - N x 2`

```
line(centroids(:,1), centroids(:,2), 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

## `centroids - 2 x N`

```
line(centroids(1,:), centroids(2,:), 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

As a minor note, the `x` and `y` variables in the `line` call look like they are coordinates for the convex hull of your shapes.  You are trying to combine these with the centroids... which doesn't really make any sense.  Stick with drawing one or the other.  If you want to draw both, then make two separate line calls:

```
line(centroids(:,1), centroids(:,2), 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
% or
% line(centroids(1,:), centroids(2,:), 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
line(x(indexes), y(indexes), 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

Don't mix apples and oranges together.

Comment: thanks alot for your reply. I tried your suggested changes but it didn´t solve my problem. Actually i want to get a stick figure of human in shape of a star. Need to draw five lines from center of object i.e.,human. One for head, two for hands and two for legs. If you know any other method, kindly let me know. I am stuck at this point and i will appreciate your help.

Comment: And yes, centroid is a Nx2 array.

Comment: Why does it "not solve your problem"? Can you explain? Can you show me what the image looks like now before the error?

Comment: Now it does not give me any lines and it has made my laptop to slow to run the code. I have attached some screenprints to my post. Hope you can help me out